# Show international phone format for international visitors only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering if there's a Javascript that I can use so when an international visitor (non-US) visits my site, they'll see an international phone format that they can follow. Basically changing the "value" to a international phone format example.

This is the code for the input field that I have...

```
<input id="phone" class="numphone" maxlength="255" 
    name="Phone_Number" type="text" tabindex="6" 
    value="(555) 123-4567" 
    onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '(555) 123-4567';}" 
    onfocus="if (this.value == '(555) 123-4567') {this.value = '';}"
/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: The format any particular person should see does not necessarily depend on where the person happens to be when using your website.

Comment: And there isn't a standard format for non-US 'phone numbers.

Comment: I think you should display both of them. You can never know which one user wants to see, and users may be using VPN which renders any script checking this thing 'annoying'.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way detect programmatically whether the visitor is “international” or “non-US”, for any meaningful definition of such concepts. Using Geolocation and other tools, you might be able to decide, perhaps with acceptable margin of error, whether the user’s device is located in US territory or not. But this won’t tell you whether the user is a European or Asian businessman visiting the US, for example, or a US citizen using a computer outside the US.

Moreover, as this seems to be about *input* format, you should simply ask users to enter the phone number in international format but perhaps imply the US if the country prefix is missing (*or* prompt for corrected information). And you should parse the phone number so that “(”, “)”, “-”, and space are ignored, because they carry no relevant information but are often typed by people who are familiar with such notations.